# How to set incrementer column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have SQL Server table `tbl_Slide_master`. It has one column `slide_position` as `int`. However when admin wants to add new slide this column incremented with 1 from existing max value of that column. and i just also want to update this field.

For further info I included this code.

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertNewSlide]
(
    @Header_text varchar(25),
    @ImageName varchar(50),
    @Img_height int,
    @Img_width int,
    @Para_text varchar(520),
    @NewId INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN TRAN;
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Slide_master]
           ([Header_text]
           ,[ImageName]
           ,[Img_height]
           ,[Img_width]
           ,[Para_text]
           ,[slide_position]
            )
          VALUES
           (@Header_text,@ImageName,@Img_height,@Img_width,@Para_text,SELECT MAX(slide_position)+1)
        SET @NewId= SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    COMMIT TRAN;
    END TRY 

    BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN;
        DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int;
        SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
        RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1);
  END CATCH;
```

There is one error occurred like

> Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_InsertNewSlide, Line 21
>   Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions
>   are allowed.

Comment: The question is very unclear - are you asking how to have an auto increment field on a table, or about the error you are getting?

Comment: For an autoincrementing column, use the `INT IDENTITY(1,1)` datatype - don't roll your own logic... (and using `SELECT MAX() + 1` is very bad and **not safe** under load - you're guaranteed to get duplicates!)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: for running stored procedure i will use "[dbo].[sp_blah]" so not problem at all.

Comment: Yes, it is still a problem. [Please read this](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) and the link @marc_s posted before just discarding advice from people with plenty of experience. What makes you think `sp_` is a ***good*** idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `VALUES` clause you have:

```
SELECT MAX(slide_position)+1
```

This is not a valid subquery as it doesn't include the table name in the query.

The logic for this incrementing field is not clear to me, so I will assume you just want the largest value currently in the table:

```
SELECT MAX(slide_position)+1 FROM tbl_Slide_master
```

However, if this is just a normal identity field, you should declare it as an `IDENTITY (1,1)` field in the table creation script and simply let SQL Server manage it..

Comment: that not solution that i found it i'm not using this like searial no i just also want to update this slide_position with update query.

Comment: @ShalinGajjar - No. This is managed by SQL Server. What you are doing is prone to problems under load.